# kafka byte[] input converted to java String very slow in overrided flink AbstractKafkaDeserializationSchema

Tags: java, arrays, string, apache-flink

i have flink app which reading mysql CDC json messages from Kafka. 5 tables json CDC strings are read and processed, and i used a overrided AbstractKafkaDeserializationSchema to turn Kafka byte[] into my customized BEAN object. but i found among 5 tables, there are 2 tables, their kafka input byte[] taken much time to converted to String than other 3 tables, worse case just stuck there minutes and even like forever and there are backpressure in flink web ui in Source subtask. the conversion is just `String strValue = new String(valueByte)`. Also i tried `new String(valueByte, "UTF-8"), new String(valueByte, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII)`, make no difference. the overrided method is just:

```
deserialize(byte[] keyBytes, byte[] valueBytes, String topic, int partition, long offset) throws IOException
```

this problem stopped me from release the app 1 week, since the conversion is so simple, i can't find any alternative ways to do it, search on stackoverflow and find some similiar complains but no working solution for me.

Comment: I'm positive that you look at the wrong point. Can you check if downstream tasks also show backpressure? What's your whole topology like? Why do you suspect these two sources to be causing the issue?

Comment: thanks for your comment, arvid, yes i checked the backpressure of all subtasks in my topology, only source has backpressure. my topology is Source/schema(byte[]->JsonNode) -> Map(JsonNode->Row)->Map(Row is wrote to mongodb). and also i add 2 current time getting before and after the new String, i can get the time taken by new String precisely.

Comment: I guess you should nanoTime to measure, since I can hardly believe that it takes ms. If it indeed is taking milliseconds, then you are right. Could you share message sizes? The operation of course depends on the length of messages. Btw have you considered not using String but rather some more light-weight alternative? Something like Avro's Utf8 https://github.com/rdblue/avro-java/blob/43e4a3c3de6fa5b0a083b2669a11e99949e01070/avro/src/main/java/org/apache/avro/util/Utf8.java#L51